# Использование всплывающих подсказок Tooltip в C#

Tags: c#

Есть **127 label**, созданных с помощью кода, создаются в событии `FormLoad` и отображаются во вкладке `tabpage2`.В событии `serialPort1_DataReceived` принимаю данные, в зависимости от значения принятых байт хочу при наведении мыши на созданные `label`, выводить в `tooltip` разные подсказки. Пишу так:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(lab[1], "Подсказка")
```

Компилятор код проглатывает, ошибок нет, но при работе программы подсказки не выводятся.

Что делать?

Comment: Представьте минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример, чтобы желающие вам помочь могли у себя запустить и проверить

Comment: " _Что делать?_ " для начала вы делайте что нибудь,вставьте код который уже был написан," _компилятор код проглатывает_ " компилятор есть не умеет сколько я знаю, по логике что написали то и происходит

Comment: `lab[1]` это что?

Comment: lab[1] это имя одного из элементов массива label, который создается при загрузке формы